# Does full garbage collection occur without old gen collection being full

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have three questions regarding garbage collection

1. I am trying to study the garbage collection in my application and I can notice that a full GC has occurred. By studying the GC logs I could find that old gen has not even used half the memory allocated to it. Then why would a full GC happen. Is there some other algorithm the JVM uses that releases the memory even when old gen is not completely utilized?
2. What can be called as a good GC trend.  I mean if the full GC occurs at every 10- 15 mins can I call the application to be in a good state.  I want to know how an ideal GC should be for an application. I know it depends considerably on the application, but there should be something to call ideal.
3. I have not set the NewSize or Newratio property. The default NewRatio in the machine seems to be 2. But I can see that my young gen is using only 1/4 th the heap size and the rest is used by tenured gen. How is this possible? All I have defined is the Xmx and permsize.

Answer (score 1):

A major collection can happen for several reasons, in most cases you can see the cause by using jstat -gccause.

Few of the reasons are
-System.gc() if called from your app or any other code that you use and relies on this call.
-When the old space occupancy fractions has been reached
-When a PermGen collection takes place
-Depending on the collector you are using CMSIncrementalMode seems to be causing major collections before the limit of the old generation.

Most likely System.gc() is the cause of your unexpected major collections, try to use the flag -XX:+DisableExcplicitGC and see if you still get them.

--

There is no trend that can describe all usages. This should be based on your needs. Does the way your GC works now affect the performance of your app/service. Do you get long stop-the-world pauses that decrease your throughput ? What do you want to achieve? And the most important what is the garbage you are generating ? Try to analyze a heap dump and see if you can somehow reduce the numbers before you go and optimize the collector.

--

It depends on the flags you are using the version of the JVM your OS etc etc... In general GC ergonomics and more specifically the option -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy will be responsible of the sizings of your generations.